# Selenium's firefox webdriver works in one machine but not another

Tags: python, firefox, ubuntu, selenium, google-compute-engine

Here is the very simple code that I am running:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()`
```

Here is the error that it causes on a google compute instance:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 77, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 98, in _wait_until_connectable
    raise WebDriverException("The browser appears to have exited "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary construct
or, check it for details.
```

On both machines I have

- `Python 2.7.6`
- `Mozilla Firefox 42.0`
- `locate selenium` returns `... /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-2.48.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rs ...`
- So, `Selenium 2.48.0`
- `lsb_release -a
  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
  Release:        14.04
  Codename:       trusty`

One machine is run on  a google compute server (it errors) and one is on a VM VirtualBox (it works), but this is the only difference that I can find and it shouidn't matter.

What other differences are there that could cause this error on one machine but not the other?

NOTE:
I am thinking maybe the google compute engine cannot open a browser window since you can only ssh into a command line? Then this problem can't be solved?

NOTE:
This code works on both machines:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS
```

But, I need to use firefox, so this is not a solution just another thing to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted the reason could be that you are running on an headless system. PhantomJS and HTMLUnit and stuf like this don't requiere to have a x-server.

Can you try to start firefox on your commandline just typing `firefox`.
If that fails with an exception like `Can't find/open display on 0.0` or smth. like this, you should use XVFB:

Here is a description how to use XVFB.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox xvfb
sudo Xvfb :10 -ac
export DISPLAY=:10
```

Now you can try to start firefox with `firefox`

The commands i copied from:
http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/

If you like to set the DISPLAY Port within your java application and just for your firefox instance you can do it like this:

```
    FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
    firefoxBinary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", ":10");

    new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, new FirefoxProfile());
```

Comment: I was using python and no java, but running the 4 lines of code concerning xvfb then opening python allowed it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I need to run 'gcloud init' then login as default. See document at step 1: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/