# Running webdrive in headless mode, Firefox is still starting up

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless

I am using Selenium webdriver. I am trying to run my code in headless mode, yet everytime I invoke it, firefox still opens up on my machine. Here's the code I'm running:

```
  @headless = Headless.new
  @headless.start    

  @profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  if @use_proxy
    p = "#{@proxy}:#{@proxy_port}"
    @profile.proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new(
      :http     => p,
      :ftp      => p,
      :ssl      => p
    )
  end
  @profile['general.useragent.override'] = @user_agent_string
  @profile["browser.privatebrowsing.autostart"] = true
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => @profile
```

Comment: Are you running on Linux and do you have xvfb installed?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment you need to use xvfb to in case you are running on linux.

I recently described it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33563013/1199731

Can you try to start firefox on your commandline just typing `firefox`.
If that fails with an exception like `Can't find/open display on 0.0` or smth. like this, you should use XVFB:

Here is a description how to use XVFB.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox xvfb
sudo Xvfb :10 -ac
export DISPLAY=:10
```

Now you can try to start firefox with `firefox` and try to run your program.

I don't know the ruby WebDriver API but in Java there is a `FirefoxBinary.setEnvironmentProperty` which you can invoke with `("DISPLAY", ":10")` to set the environment variable programmatically.